# Cannot choose albums, audiobooks etc in MPMEDIAPICKERCONTROLLER

Tags: objective-c, mpmediapickercontroller

I am coding an iOs App that uses MPMUSICPLAYER. I started with a tutorial app, that worked just fine. Then I added stuff to play internet radio. Somewhere on the road suddenly the Media Picker only let me choose songs, no albums, playlists etc. When I search for audiobook titles the app crashes with weird errors:NSInvalidArgumentException reason: UIApplication isResuming unrecognized selector.
And before that:BEGIN IMEDIATE could unexpectedly not be stepped after 0:8/ attempt to write a readonly database.

```
- (IBAction)openMediaPicker:(id)sender {
[self.player stop]; // stop the Internet Radio
MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAny];
mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES; // this is the default   
[self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES];
[mediaPicker release]; }


- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {
// We need to dismiss the picker
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

// Assign the selected item(s) to the music player and start playback.
[self.musicPlayer stop];
[self.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];
[self.musicPlayer play]; }
```

Whatever I do, I can't come back to the normal behaviour. The app does play DRM songs from iTunes.
Any help very much appreciated!